# Heroku: Privacy error "Your connection is not private" is displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Privacy error `Your connection is not private` is displayed (with using Chrome) when I try to access the url which I registered as `CNAME`.

I developed Rails app, and this is the first time to use Heroku.

Although the error isn't displayed when I use the original url such as `https://floating-fortress-99999.herokuapp.com/`, the error is displayed when I use `www.my_app.com` which I get.

All of the error messages on the browser are as followings;

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.my_app.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This server could not prove that it is www.my_app.com; its security certificate is from *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

I can display `www.my_app.com` when I click the link `Proceed to www.my_app.com (unsafe)` on the browser.

Is it possible to avoid displaying 'Privacy error' ?

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're most likely using `force_ssl = true` in your configuration, however you don't have a valid and authorized SSL certificate installed on your server.

To fix the error you have two possibilities:

- Disable SSL via `force_ssl = false` (not recommended)
- Purchase an SSL certificate issued from a certifying authority and install it on your server (such as nginx or Apache)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Anthony E. I understand why this error is displayed.
By the way, I found CloudFlare give us free SSL. I will try it.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue hi I am facing of with same problem on my site though I am using CloudFlare I am facing of with same problem and my ssl certificate is flexible. How did you get rid off this problem?

Answer (score 8):

**Updated Answer in 2020**

Heroku now has Automated Certificate Management for all tiers above the free tier that allows for a ridiculously easy setup to have https working for your website.

To set this up:

1. In Heroku upgrade the tier to hobbyist or above (starting at
   $7/month)
2. In the CLI run the command `heroku certs:auto:enable -a yourappname`
3. In the CLI run command `heroku domains`. You should get a list of your custom domains and a list of the their DNS targets. After running the commands above the DNS targets you get should end in `.herokudns.com` instead of `.herokuapp.com`.
4. Now in your DNS (GoDaddy, or whatever DNS you are using) update the DNS to make sure that its pointed to the new `.herokudns.com` app instead of the generic `.herokuapp.com`

You might of course have to wait some time after finishing those steps for the DNS change to take effect. But now you have everything set up alright! Ta Da, you have DNS working for you!

For more info on any of those steps check [heroku's article here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management#setup)

Comment: is it possible to just turn on ACM and keep using the default subdomain e.g. somethin.herokuapp.com? I turned on ACM, I have a paid tier, but the browser still says my cert is invalid. i have a domain for front-end and i'd like to keep my backend on the default domain

Comment: Which domain did you have ACM turned on for, FE or BE domain?

Comment: thanks for responding I already solved my problem and added it as an answer to this question (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65613020/1869111). I turned on ACM for BE domain and did not add custom domain, I keep on using the url generated by heroku. I thought I had to add a domain to make SSL work but the problem was somewhere else. ACM is really trivial to use.

Answer (score 5):

You get "Your connection is not private" error while loading your Heroku application through a new domain name because the existing SSL certificate is not valid for it.

As you can see from the error message:

> This server could not prove that it is www.my_app.com; its security certificate is from *.herokuapp.com.

It is only valid for *.herokuapp.com domain name, in this case, it can be your-app-name.herokuapp.com. When you create a new CNAME and use that domain name instead of your-app-name.herokuapp.com, the exisiting SSL certificate can't validate it and displays this error to you.

To bypass this SSL error temporarily, you can enter chrome://flags into Google Chrome address bar to access advanced settings, locate "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost" and enable this. By doing so, you can turn off this waring temporarily on your browser (only).

The solution to resolve this issue permanently is to get a new SSL for your domain. You can use the SSL Endpoint add-on from Heroku to use a private SSL with your domain name. This add-on charges you $20 per month. For more details of this add-on, [read it from here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/ssl) or [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint).

Another option is to use Heroku SSL, a free feature that Heroku is currently offering. It seems they want to replace SSL Endpoint by this one. To find out how to install SSL for your domain name with Heroku SSL, [read this article from NameCheap.com](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10050/33/installing-an-ssl-certificate-on-heroku-ssl).

Source: [Fix Your Connection Is Not Private Error In Your Browser](https://bytebitebit.com/687/your-connection-is-not-private/)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that might come across this -

I've worked for a company that used cisco anyconnect which also included Umbrella DNS protection.

It was systemwide (win 10) service that checked the urls and if (for whatever reason) decided it was dangerous, it showed the SSL error.

I just uninstalled the app since I did not need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just needed to put https://sitename.herokuapp.com instead of heroku.com

Comment: omg I would have never checked there. Thank you